# Verilog Vending Machine Error

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm designing a project for school, I'm required to make the code work with Verilog.  The goal is to have 4 inputs (buttons on the FPGA), quarter, nickel, dime, and reset, as well as switches to identify what kind of burrito I want to purchase (Bean burrito, steak burrito, and chicken burrito).  I need to display the current money inserted on a seven segment display.  The problem I'm having is that the seven segment display is not working.  It only displays my default, none of the switches work and neither do the buttons.  I found this website looking for help, and discovered other examples, I tried following some of them but I'm still stuck.  I would appreciate the help, this is my first time coding period. I couldn't insert the entire code for some reason, so I put the main parts.  I think the beginning is whats wrong.

```
module LabX(quarter, nickel, dime, BB, CB, SB, clk, reset, current_state, R, L, next_state, give_BB, give_CB, give_SB, Rssd, Lssd, ld);
input  quarter, nickel, dime, BB, CB, SB, clk, reset, R, L; 
output next_state, give_BB, give_CB, give_SB;
output [6:0] Rssd, Lssd, current_state;
output [2:0] ld;
reg [6:0] current_state, next_state, give_BB, give_CB, give_SB, Rssd, Lssd, ld;
parameter cent0 = 0, cent5= 1, cent10 = 2, cent15=3, cent20 =4, cent25 =5, cent30=6, cent35=7, cent40=8, cent45=9, cent50=10, cent55=11, cent60=12, cent65=13, cent70=14, cent75=15, cent80=16, cent85=17, cent90=18, cent95=19, cent100=20;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
if(reset)
current_state = cent0;
    else
current_state = next_state;
end
always @(nickel or dime or quarter or BB or CB or SB or reset)
begin
case(current_state)
    cent0: begin
    if(nickel)  
      next_state = cent5;
          else if(dime)
      next_state = cent10;
          else if(quarter)
      next_state = cent25;
          else if(reset)
      next_state = cent0;
    end
```

I continued this process and to show when you have enough to purchase I entered this...

```
cent55: begin
  if(nickel)  
    next_state = cent60;
       else if(dime)
    next_state = cent65; 
       else if(quarter)
    next_state = cent80;
       else if(reset)  
    next_state = cent0;
  if(BB)
    give_BB = 1;
       else if(CB)
    give_CB = 1;
       else if(SB)
    give_SB = 0;
end
```

For the Seven segment display I entered the code as follows:

```
case (current_state)        
    cent0:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent5:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent10:Rssd=7'b1111110; 
    cent15:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent20:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent25:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent30:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent35:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent40:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent45:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent50:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent55:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent60:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent65:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent70:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent75:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent80:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent85:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent90:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    cent95:Rssd=7'b1011011;
    cent100:Rssd=7'b1111110;
    BB:Rssd=7'b0011111;
    CB:Rssd=7'b0011111;
    SB:Rssd=7'b0011111;
default: Rssd = 7'b1111110;
    endcase
 end
endmodule
```

I did this for Lssd as well.  I believe the UCF file is correct, something is wrong with my code.

Comment: I don't think it's easy to pinpoint what is wrong based on the input that you have given. Did you try to simulate your code in a testbench? Could it be that the FPGA building process gives you some errors or warnings? Perhaps you could try routing some of the buttons directly to some of the display segments, just to see if you are able to toggle some segments in the display based on button input?

Comment: By the way, are your button inputs directly coupled to the physical buttons on the FPGA? In that case, at least you must ensure that you synchronize the inputs (double flops) to the local clock, and that you do some edge detection when pushed. To get it reliable you may even have to add some debouncing logic. (Google it to see what I mean.)

Comment: You need to look at your always sensitivity list.  You don't have current_state in the list.  
Something else you might need to look at is this:
reg [6:0] current_state, next_state, give_BB, give_CB, give_SB, Rssd, Lssd, ld;
Because you start the line with reg[6:0], all of the registers you declare in this line will be reg[6:0].  On the surface, it appears that some of those are not supposed to be 7 bit values.

Comment: Okay let me try that Rich, should I make a second reg for the inputs with less bits?

Comment: `@(nickel or dime or quarter or BB or CB or SB or reset)` is so 1995 (Verilog-1995). Since Verilog-2001, the preferred method is to use an auto-sensitivity lists `@*` (or `@(*)`). As coded, it looks like all the `give_*` are inferred latches with no way to get back to 0; resulting behavior is free burritos after initial purchase. A 21-state state-machine is overly complicated for a vending machine. Would you code it this way if the requirements were to handle five dollars worth in nickels? Wouldn't a simple conditional adder be more effective to keep track of current amount?